# Angular 2 Primeng DataType Issue

Tags: angular, primeng

I am reading my data from a json file and displaying it into PrimeNG table. I want the headers of PrimeNG table to be datatype sensitive i.e., on giving an input of number in the search box of header of it should come as number not allowed in alert box.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you leave an image for your case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyup event on your input element for header like this :

```
<input type=“input” (keyup)=“checkDatatype(myInput.value)” #myInput />
```

In component:

```
checkDatatype(input: any) {
if (// check for your type) {
     // display alert, if input is not the expected type
     }
}
```